# Bouncing off inclined surface

Tags: actionscript-3, math, physics

I can calculate distance between inclined line and my ball (with normal vector), But how can I calculate new velocity?

[image: Illustrative image]

Comment: Look into vectors. Depending on the restitution provided by the ball surface contact you merely break the magnitude of the initial velocity down into the horizontal and vertical components using the sine and cosine of the angle the ball makes with the surface... This is better asked at http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am so confused :
http://paste.org/67250

Comment: @Jav1993id if you have updates, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18735741/edit) to include the new information. Don't put code on external sites and ask us to look at it, especially sites which hide their content from people using adblockers!

Comment: You shouldn't be attempting this kind of thing without some understanding of vectors and the physics involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anders' answer was a good one but I realise that you may not have a great mathematical back ground so I will elaborate. The problem you have at the moment is poorly stated. However, see the following figure

[image]

This will allow us to derive the equation you require. Now, the scalar product of two vectors **a** and **b**, **a.b** gives the magnitude of **a** multiplied by the projection of **b** onto **a**. Basically, if we take **n** as a unit vector (magnitude 1 in each component direction) then **a.n** gives the magnitude of the components of **a** which act in the direction of **n**.

So, splitting the velocity components into those parallel and perpendicular to the plain; to get the velocity **V** we first split **U** into components.

Perpendicular to the plane in direction **n**, we have a vector velocity **w** = (**U.n**) **n**. This means that in fact we can write **U** = (**U.n**) **n** + [**U** - (**U.n**) **n**]. This is saying that **U** is made up of the perpendicular component of itself + the parallel component of itself. Now, -**V** is very similar to **U** but the parallel components acts in the reverse direction, so we can write -**V** = (**U.n**) **n** - [**U** - (**U.n**) **n**].

Combining the above gives the result Anders stated, i.e. **V** = **U** -2[(**U.n**) **n**]. The dot/scalar product is defined as **a.b** = |a||b|cos(A) where A is the angle between the vectors laid together tail-to-tail, this should enable you to solve your problem.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If The vector v=(vx,vy) is the initial velocity and the plane has normal n=(nx,ny) then the new reflected velocity vector r will be

```
r=v−2(v⋅n)*n
```

The product (v⋅n) is the dot product of v and n, defined as vx*nx+vy*ny. Note that the plane normal must be normalized (length 1.0). A related question with the same answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector

Comment: You have not defined d here and the formula that you state does not look right to me.

Comment: Oh I switched between d and v half way, there should only be a "v" (initial velocity vector). Corrected.

Comment: Don't for get to +1 and accept his answer!

Comment: Mind you, this assumes a fully elastic reflection, i.e. no kinetic energy is lost in the process